# keep on getting '404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]' error when getting wine repository

Tags: wine, repository, add-apt-repository

I have been trying to download wine through https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu and I keep on getting this error when adding the repository using this command: Sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ groovy main' i have tried everything I have found online and nothing has worked.

**Logs:**

```
Hit:1 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu artful InRelease
Hit:2 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Hit:4 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
Hit:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy InRelease                
Hit:6 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:8 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]      
Ign:10 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable InRelease                     
Hit:11 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release                       
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease               
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple PPAs that're not supported anymore.  Hence the 404s.

---

### WebUpd8Team Java PPA

```
Err:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
```

The WebUpd8Team PPAs are all old and deprecated and do not support Focal.  Further, if you are using this to get Sun / Oracle JAVA, the Sun/Oracle licensing has changed in the past two years and you **no longer can distribute the Oracle Java flavors due to the licensing change.**

---

### Ubuntu WINE PPA

```
Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
```

The Ubuntu Wine PPA has not been maintained for at least three dev cycles of Ubuntu now.

Instead, you need to [follow the instructions from WineHQ Upstream and use the WineHQ repos](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) to get the latest Wine on your systems.  There's no way around this.

---

See also [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Comment: You're fast!  I was in the process of answering and you beat me to it!  +1 for speed alone.  ;)

Comment: @Terrance Well, I was already writing.  And this is also closed as another post.  Except that I didn't have that link when I was writing already ;)

Comment: so what do i do about the `WebUpd8Team Java PPA` as it does not seem to be working without it